# Error message : If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead React JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having issue with my project. Everything works fine until i add the Navbar component to the skills one then i get the error message below. As soon as i remove Navbar from skill component everything runs just fine.

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Can someone tell me what i have done wrong, please?

Leo

Skills component

```
import { data } from '../../SkillData';
import SkillsList from "./SkillsList";
import Header from './Header';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
function Speakers () {
    return (
        <>
        <Navbar />
        <Header />
        <SkillsList data={data} />
        </>
    );
}

export default Speakers;
```

Navbar Component

```
import Image from "next";

const navbarData = [
    {   "id": "1",
        "title": "home",
        "ref": "#home"
    },
    {   "id":"2",
        "title": "Skills",
        "ref": "#skills"
    },
    {   "id":"3",
        "title": "The List",
        "ref": "#theList"
    },
    {   "id": "4",
        "title": "Team",
        "ref": "#team"
    },
    {   "id": "5",
        "title": "Contact",
        "ref": "#contact"
    },
];

function Navbar() {
    
    return (
        <>
            <nav className= "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
                <div className="container">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">
                        <Image src="./knowledge Memo.svg" alt="..." /></a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        Menu
                        <i className="fas fa-bars ms-1"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                            {navbarData.map((link, idx) => {

                                return (
                                    <li key={`Navbar${JSON.stringify(link)}`} data-index={idx} className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" href={link.ref}>{link.title}</a></li>

                                );
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

index.js component

```
//import Head from 'next/head'
import Skills from '../src/components/Skills';

const Home = () => {

  return (    
   <Skills />
  );
}
export default Home;
```

header.js component

```
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.scss";
const Header = () => {
    return (
      <header className={styles.masthead}>
              <div className={styles.container}>
                  <div className={styles.masthead_subheading}>React Jedi Road Map</div>
                  <div className={styles.masthead_heading , "text-uppercase"}>this is the way!</div>
                  <a className="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" href="#services">Tell Me More</a>
              </div>
        </header>
     );
  }
  
  export default Header;
```

skilllist component

```
import Skill from "../components/Skill";
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.scss";
import { data } from '../../SkillData';

function SkillsList () {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container, "container"}>
        <div className="row">
          {data.map(function (skillCard) {         
            return (
              <Skill key={skillCard.id} skillCard={skillCard} />
            )
          })}
  
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default SkillsList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Navbar component: I would think the `JSON.stringify()` for the key in your map function is synchronous, but try putting the index as the key to see if it resolves it.

Comment: I have tried with id instead of JSON.Stringify() but it did not work @anolan23

Comment: try: `key={idx}`

Comment: it's still not making it @anolan23

Comment: ```<Image src="./knowledge Memo.svg" alt="..." />``` something looks off for the src possibly. Make sure you are using a proper src

Comment: thanks for spotting this one, src path was not correct indeed but the error message is still there. @anolan23

Answer (score 0):

```
key={`Navbar${JSON.stringify(link)}`}
```

Very likely this is the problem. You can't make object a string, especially not with JSON.stringify() which returns JSON string from an object. Your data is already strinigified anyways. So, *link* is an object and it can't be just inserted into string like that. Rather use id or idx for keys since it anyways makes more sense as someone previously said.

Comment: Any idea  @cedavitkovac?

Comment: key = {link.id} and maybe make navbarData as normal onbject, not strigified, ex replace "id":"1" with id:1, leave quotes only when value is string

Comment: tried it but does not work either @cedivitkovac

Comment: @cedivitkovac nothing works

Comment: Can you send me github repo or the code so I can try myself?

Comment: Hi guys, it seems both of you were right. @anolan23. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In Navbar component:

```
import Image from “next/image”
```

instead of

```
import Image from “next”
```

Also, make sure to specify `width` and `height` props on Image component. Or use `layout=“fill”`